# How to query search numbers in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need a search query.
Age value 10 - 15 , 20 - 25 , 17 - 19 , 12 - 59 , 2 - 19 , 18 - 40 , 10 - 20

I send 10 - 25 and I want to get results by matching the numbers

```
<?php 
  $Age1 = 10;
  $Age2 = 25;

  $Age = $Age1." - ".$Age2;

  $stmt = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM job_post_p1 where Age LIKE '%" . $Age .  "%'");

?>
```

Thanks to All

Comment: Can you add the sample data for `job_post_p1` table?

Comment: You want to grab rows that have an age in between those two ages? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm

Comment: We cannot provide the correct answer unless you provide the sample record in table for age

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the BETWEEN operator, it selects values within a given range.

Example:

```
$stmt = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM job_post_p1 where Age BETWEEN 10 AND 25");
```

Comment: Yes, it selects the values where the age is between 10 - 25

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you need is between operator. The between operator aims to select values within a given range. In your scenario, an age range. This operator is inclusive. This means that begin and end values are included.

```
<?php

$Age1 = 10;
$Age2 = 25;

$stmt = mysqli_query(
    $con,
    "SELECT * " .
    "FROM job_post_p1 " .
    "WHERE Age BETWEEN $Age1 AND $Age2"
);
```

Answer (score -1):

`$stmt = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM job_post_p1 where Age BETWEEN 10 AND 25");`

Comment: You should explain **why** your answer is the correct one, why it should be used. You just posting the code saying "this is it" doesn't answer the question of **why** that's right, how can anyone else learn from it?

Comment: Thanks for advice